# Emulating standard dialog size using dialog_min_width_minor

Tags: android, layout, dialog

For some reason I can't use a Dialog, so I'm just emulating it with a View hierarchy. I want to make my dialog appear in the center of the screen with a standard Android dialog size.

I found a resource value [dialog_min_width_minor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html#dialog_min_width_minor), but how do I use it? When I try to do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> <!-- provides the gray semi-transparent background !-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_container"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I just get an exception:

> Binary XML file line #8: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a bit of time and came upon [this example](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro/blob/f665de19a55b769990d75fef6723eb2341727381/alertdialogpro-core/src/main/res/values-v11/adp_core_themes.xml). You can emulate a Dialog using an Activity with this theme.

Interestingly enough, the AppCompat library has its own definition of these properties, but they aren't lined up with the standard sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, `android.R.dimen.dialog_min_width_minor` is defined like this in one case:

```
<item type="dimen" name="dialog_min_width_minor">95%</item>
```

You can't set this as a width in an xml layout, but you can systematically use it to set the width in your activity/fragment/view. You can do something like this:

```
// Get the percentage as defined by android.R.dimen.dialog_min_width_minor
Resources resources = context.getResources();
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
resources.getValue(android.R.dimen.dialog_min_width_minor, typedValue, true);
float percentage = typedValue.getFraction(1, 1);

// Get the width of the display
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int displayWidth = size.x;

// set the width of your view
// view.width = displayWidth * percentage <--pseudocode
```